# Error trying to reinstall rugged gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rugged

I'm trying to reinstall rugged as it's causing issues with another program (Dandelion Deploy).

I've recently updated my RVM and Ruby, and installed cmake and pkg-config again, but I get this error when I run the following command: `gem install rugged`

```
Fetching: rugged-0.22.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rugged:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/J/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p645/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150605-56781-qfplzm.rb extconf.rb
checking for gmake... no
checking for make... yes
checking for cmake... yes
checking for pkg-config... yes
 -- cmake .. -DBUILD_CLAR=OFF -DTHREADSAFE=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-fPIC -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -G "Unix Makefiles"
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/J/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p645/bin/ruby
    --use-system-libraries
extconf.rb:13:in `sys': ERROR: 'cmake .. -DBUILD_CLAR=OFF -DTHREADSAFE=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-fPIC -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -G "Unix Makefiles"' failed (RuntimeError)
    from extconf.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:65:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:65:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:62:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:62:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/J/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rugged-0.22.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/J/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-11/2.0.0/rugged-0.22.2/gem_make.out
```

I'm a frontender, so this is way out of my comfort zone. Any help appreciated!

Mac OSX 10.7.5, Lion

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Try this - sudo apt-get install cmake

Comment: Sorry, running mac osx 10.7.5 (I know, I know)

Comment: See the install of [rugged](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged) gem repository on github. On OS X : `brew install cmake`

Comment: I've already installed cmake like that. When I run it again, it says: 

`Warning: cmake-3.2.2 already installed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

I installed the latest version of XCode I could (4.6.3) on OSX 10.7.5.

To get dandelion working, I installed the following gems: rugged, dandelion and net-sftp

and everything worked again.